# SST: How to deploy multiple stacks using the same RestApi with common base path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, serverless-stack

I'm trying to migrate our Serverless Framework application to SST. We currently have 2 stacks that use the same REST API Gateway and all paths start with `/v1`.

Following the SST doco [here](https://docs.sst.dev/constructs/ApiGatewayV1Api#importing-an-existing-rest-api) I was able to add routes from two stacks into one API Gateway. However, when using the same path part i.e. `/v1` the deployment fails and I get an error message saying

```
Another resource with the same parent already has this name: v1 (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 409, Request ID: ...)
```

Ok, I thought I would need to reference the route resource `/v1` and use the `importedPaths` property on ApiGatwayV1's `cdk` property, also shown in the doco example.

```
export function Api2({ stack }: StackContext) {
  const { api } = use(Api1);

  const restApi = RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(stack, "api", {
    restApiId: api.cdk.restApi.restApiId,
    rootResourceId: api.cdk.restApi.restApiRootResourceId,
  });
  const v1 = restApi.root.resourceForPath("/v1");

  new ApiGatewayV1Api(stack, "second-api", {
    cdk: {
      restApi,
      importedPaths: { "/v1": v1.resourceId },
    },
    routes: {
      "GET /v1/todo-list": "packages/functions/src/todo.handler",
    },
  });
}
```

But no, I still run into the same issue. Debugging the `v1.resourceId` reveals that the id looks like a temporary/internal reference rather than an AWS id `${Token[TOKEN.781]}`, but I would have expected it would be resolved?

SST deploys the stacks in one go whereas our two Serverless stacks are deployed using two separate commands. The 2nd stack would be able to retrieve the real resource id from the 1st stack's output, so maybe that is why it's succeeding.

Anyway, I kinda think that having a common base route/path would not be such an exotic construct.

To quickly reproduce and play around with the setup, I've created a new SST project and modified it so it reflects our setup: https://github.com/robbash/multi-stack-apigw

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: I can add a full answer later, but you can use stage variables to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Pharmakon thanks for your comment. Technically, I'd see this as a workaround. I ended up using another workaround for now by using custom domain names and `v1` as path in API mappings. For as long as there is no real solution, it might be worth writing up your comment as an answer. I'll likely add mine later too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve this issue. Maybe it's a little bit too late for you but it may help others.

Not Working code:

```
  const  api = new ApiGatewayV1Api(stack, 'api', {
  cdk: {
    restApi: RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(stack, 'RestApi', {
      restApiId: process.env.REST_API_ID ?? '',
      rootResourceId: process.env.REST_API_ROOT_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }),
    importedPaths: {
      '/api/admin': process.env.REST_API_ADMIN_RESOURCE_ID ?? '',
      '/api': process.env.REST_API_API_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }
  },
  routes: {
    'POST /api/newsletters/subscriptions/unsubscribe': {
      ...
    },
    'POST /api/newsletters/subscriptions/subscribe': {
      ...
    },
  }
```

Still not working code:

```
  const  api = new ApiGatewayV1Api(stack, 'api', {
  cdk: {
    restApi: RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(stack, 'RestApi', {
      restApiId: process.env.REST_API_ID ?? '',
      rootResourceId: process.env.REST_API_ROOT_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }),
    importedPaths: {
      '/api/admin': process.env.REST_API_ADMIN_RESOURCE_ID ?? '',
      '/api/newsletter': process.env.REST_API_API_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }
  },
  routes: {
    'POST /api/newsletters/newsletters/subscriptions/unsubscribe': {
      ...
    },
    'POST /api/newsletters/newsletters/subscriptions/subscribe': {
      ...
    },
  }
```

The API Gateway is right, but the Lambda trigger is not correct because it searches for newsletters/newsletters:
[API Gateway api list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqWPJ.png)

**Solution**:

```
  const  api = new ApiGatewayV1Api(stack, 'api', {
  cdk: {
    restApi: RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(stack, 'RestApi', {
      restApiId: process.env.REST_API_ID ?? '',
      rootResourceId: process.env.REST_API_ROOT_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }),
    importedPaths: {
      '/api/admin': process.env.REST_API_ADMIN_RESOURCE_ID ?? '',
      '/api': process.env.REST_API_API_RESOURCE_ID ?? ''
    }
  },
  routes: {
    'POST /api/newsletters/subscriptions/unsubscribe': {
      ...
    },
    [[INSERT ONE API AT THE TIME]]
  }
```

If you **deploy one API at the time**, the deploy will go successful and you have your intended result. Yes, it's a workaround but the final result is what we needed!

Hope it helps